# Как изменить шаблон Generate Getter and Setter в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Мне нужно изменить шаблон  Generate Getter and Setter с

```
  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;    
  }
```

на

```
 public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public MyClass setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Если речь о расширении [Getter and Setter Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=afmicc.GetterAndSetterGenerator), то нужно менять шаблон кода в коде самого расширения.

Comment: @insolor нет это не то расширение, но принцип тот же. Есть команда которая генерирует код. Если существует шаблон то как и где что поменять?

Comment: А для Java какие расширения установлены?

Comment: Microsoft java extension pack.

Comment: У меня он установлен, но именно такого пункта в меню действий нет. В любом случае, нужно сначала определить в каком расширении реализовано это действие (можно например пробовать по одному отключать расширения), а там уже будет понятнее как его конфигурировать.

Comment: Посмотрите на коже Refactor в контекстном меню мыши. Generate getter and setter

Comment: "No refactorings available"

Comment: А за что минус?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная функция не поддерживается нативно Visual Studio Code. Поэтому, отвечая на Ваш вопрос, из коробки этого никак этого сделать нельзя. Если Вам необходимо получить соответствующий функционал, то имеется несколько вариантов:

1. https://github.com/afmicc/getter-setter-generator

Можно сделать кастомные геттеры и сеттеры.

2. IntelliJ IDEA

Можно настраивать какие геттеры и сеттеры генерировать.

3. Использовать текстовые экспандеры, такие PhraseExpander или AutoHotKey, которые позволяют обрабатывать текст из буфера обмена соответствующим образом.